# Считать в строку текстовый файл, который я кладу в этот же jar

Tags: файлы, java

я пишу

```
Object resource = BitrixComponent.class.getResourceAsStream("templates/description.txt");
              String template = resource.toString();
              System.out.println(template);
```

выводит `java.io.BufferedInputStream@1fd3e64`

а не текст с файла(

Comment: > String template = resource.toString();

в этой строке какая-то ересь.

Comment: getResourceAsStream

А что это за метод? 
Мне кажется, ресурсами загрузчик рулит.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас в getResourceAsStream() возвращает InputStream. Это не объект. Поэтому нужно конвертировать поток в строку, например так:

```
String template = IOUtils.toString(resource, "UTF-8");
```

Или любым другим образом:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/

Comment: InputStream input = Form.class.getResourceAsStream("templates/description");
       String template = Form.getStringFromInputStream(resource);
       System.out.println(template);
 

Не работает

Comment: Что значит не работает? Что выдает? Полный код кто будет приводить?